# Crear una entrada personalizada para Ion-Select

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic-framework

Estoy trabajando con **ion-select** y requiero agregar un elemento nuevo en caso de no existir dicho elemento en la lista, habia pensado en seleccionar un elemento espesifico del  select y con ayuda de un alert ingresar un nuevo campo pero tengo algun tipo de error, mi codigo es el siguiente

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.page.scss'],
})
export class IndexPage implements OnInit {
  public currentColor: string;
  public colors: Array<string>;
  constructor(public alertController: AlertController) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.colors = ['Custom', 'Brown', 'Dark'];
    this.currentColor = 'Brown';
  }

  selectChanged(selectedColor) {
    if (selectedColor === 'Custom') {
      this.inputCustomColorValue();
    } else {
      this.currentColor = selectedColor;
    }
  }

  async inputCustomColorValue() {
    const inputAlert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Enter your custom color:',
      inputs: [ { type: 'text', placeholder: 'type in' } ],
      buttons: [ { text: 'Cancel' }, { text: 'Ok' } ]
    });
    inputAlert.onDidDismiss((data) => {
        const customColorName: string = data.data.values[0];
        if (customColorName) {
          const indexFound = this.colors.findIndex(color => color === customColorName);
          if (indexFound === -1) {
            this.colors.push(customColorName);
            this.currentColor = customColorName;
          } else {
            this.currentColor = this.colors[indexFound];
          }
        }
      });
    await inputAlert.present();

  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Le has echado un vistazo a la [documentación ion-select](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select) de ionic?

Comment: Te recuerdo echarle un vistazo también al [tour] para que aprendas un poquito más sobre StackOverflow y como preguntar, y de paso obtienes tu primera medalla.

Comment: @JuanJosé  primeramente muchas gracias por tus comentarios, y bueno  pues si revise la documentación pero no logro dar con lo que necesito pues, cualquier aporte es bienvenido ya que soy nuevo en esto de crear aplicaciones con ionic

Comment: ¿Puedes pegar el código que tienes con el `ion-select`? Mira [ask] y [edit] tu pregunta para modificar el snippet (que no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta) y poner código de lo que has intentado. Saludos.

Comment: @JuanJosé en pegado  mi codigo, por alguna razon  tengo un problema  en la linea **inputAlert.onDidDismiss**